# Weights Not Trainable with `tf.contrib.layers.recompute_grad`

Tags: tensorflow, keras

When I use `tf.contrib.layers.recompute_grad` on a layer, the trainable weights are eliminated. How do I save the weights that are recalculated on the backwards pass at each epoch?

Comment: No reply after 3 years. Nice job stackoverflow